# Passing structure members to a function

Tags: c++, structure

I've recently started coding in c++ and right now I'm dealing with structures....and here's my problem

this is my basic struct.

```
struct myStruct
{
    string A;
    int B;
} myStruct[100];
```

I want to pass the string in '`myStruct`'(for all the elements in array of structure) to a sorting function(I'm using the inbuilt sort function). How do I do that ?I want all the strings sorted...
I've tried my best to explain my problem . I hope you get it and help me with it..

Comment: You want to sort the strings or the array of structs by the string?

Comment: You can try google first. I believe that this explanation with examples is enough http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz/.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, and you want to sort your array based on the string `A` in each struct, you need to inform `std::sort` how to compare your structs.

One way is to add `operator<` for your custom type.

```
bool operator< (myStruct const& lhs, myStruct const& rhs) {
  return lhs.A < rhs.A;
}
```

Another way is to pass `std::sort` a comparison function object:

```
std::sort( std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray),
           [](myStruct const& lhs, myStruct const& rhs)
           { return lhs.A < rhs.A; } );
```

Comment: I feel like it's a good idea mentioning that passing a function pointer will probably be slower than passing a lambda (or a function object, which is what a lambda is).